# 1 tag multiple UILabels in xcode, iphone

Tags: iphone, tags, uilabel

So I have many labels in my app that contain the same text.  I am localizing them, and would like to know if its possible for me to tag them all with the same number and assign the new text that way.

currently when I have tested it only recognizes the first label with the tag.

I really want to save myself from having all these repeat outlets

Comment: more details please... maybe some code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

You can tag them with a integer number because in inheritance tree `NSObject` is the super class to `UIView`,

And `NSObject` has an integer property called `tag` .

USE tag like below

```
myLabel1.tag = 1;
myLabel2.tag = 2;
...........
...........
myLabeln.tag = n;
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer but i am aware of tagging, i was trying to use the same number tag for multiple labels.  I don't think its possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little inclear from your question what your problem is, but I am assuming from your question that you want to be able to update all your UILabels which are located at different places within your app with the same text.

You could create a global header file that contains an NSString which holds the text for all your labels, and then `#include` this header in all view controllers which contain labels which need to show this this text. Then whenever you update the NSString in the global header you update any labels that are currently in view or about to be viewed aswell. This can be done from within your `IBAction` methods, as well as implimenting the `viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method. Whenever a view that contains relevent labels comes into view, it will apply the value of the NSString in your global header and update its labels.